# Remove certain item from list

Tags: string, list, python-2.7

I'm working out how to remove a specific item from a list.

```
"peppers", "cheese", "mushrooms", "bananas", "peppers"
```

I can locate the item "peppers", and change it to "gone!", but I really want to deleting the item, using

```
del blist[idx]
```

But that causes an error and I don't know why.

```
myList = ["peppers", "cheese", "mushrooms", "bananas", "peppers"]

def findInList (needle, haystack):
    needle = needle.lower()
    findy = []
    # loops over list elements
    for i in range(0, len(haystack)):
        temp = haystack[i].lower()
        idx = temp.find(needle)
        if (idx != -1): findy.append(i)
    return findy

def deleteItemInList(alist, blist):
    for i in range(0, len(alist)):
        idx = alist[i]
        blist[idx] = "Gone!"
        # del blist[idx]

# find items in list
mySearch = findInList("Peppers", myList)

# remove item from list
deleteItemInList(mySearch, myList)

print myList
```

Traceback: as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "delete_in_list.py", line 23, in <module>
    deleteItemInList(mySearch, myList)
  File "delete_in_list.py", line 16, in deleteItemInList
    blist[idx] = "Gone!"
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Could someone look over the code above and point out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Can you please show the actual traceback?

Comment: It's generally a terrible idea to iterate over a list and modify it at the same time, and generally better to construct a new list.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Instead of deleting items at that point in the loop I should be looking to find all other elements that I need and add them to a new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! Whilst iterating over the list deleting items in the list I was effectively sawing off the branch I was sitting on.
You need to loop over the list in reverse:

```
def deleteItemInList(alist, blist):
    for i in range(len(alist) -1, -1, -1):
        idx = alist[i]
        del blist[idx]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension for this.

```
def removeWord(needle, haystack):
    return [word for word in haystack if word.lower() != needle.lower()]
```

Answer (score 0):

To find an element use this function. Or alternatively just define it as usual:

```
>>> find = lambda _list, query: [item.lower() for item in _list].index(query.lower())

>>> l = ['red', 'pepper']
>>> q = 'Pepper'
>>> find(l, q)
1
```

To remove by index just use `del`:

```
>>> del l[find(l, q)]
>>> l
['red']
```